The 'pkg_resources' is deprecated
When I'm running 'rasa init', I received that error:
D:\Program\anaconda\envs\Rasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\shared\utils\validation.py:134: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  import pkg_resources
D:\Program\anaconda\envs\Rasa\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:3154: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('mpl_toolkits')`.
Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
  declare_namespace(pkg)
D:\Program\anaconda\envs\Rasa\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:3154: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('ruamel')`.
Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
  declare_namespace(pkg)


I thought I had to update setuptools but it seems to be the latest version (75.1.0). I am using python 3.8.20, how to resolve this error?
I tried to upgrade setuptools but it's the latest version (75.1.0).

This is not an error. It is a warning. It is meant for the authors of rasa, not you.

@Dunes: It is also a warning to the users of this package that something might change in the (near) future....


I am using python 3.8.20, how to resolve this error?

This is not an Error but a Warning. Let's look at what it says:

D:\Program\anaconda\envs\Rasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\shared\utils\validation.py:134: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html

Opening the link in the DeprecationWarning shows a useful information:

Use of pkg_resources is deprecated in favor of importlib.resources, importlib.metadata and their backports (importlib_resources, importlib_metadata). Some useful APIs are also provided by packaging (e.g. requirements and version parsing). Users should refrain from new usage of pkg_resources and should work to port to importlib-based solutions.

So stop using pkg_resources and port to importlib-based solutions. See Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources.
